# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I was transferring my magento website from server to local and changed my databse credential in app->etc->local.xml

Here is local.xml file

```
<db>
     <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
</db>
<default_setup>
     <connection>
          <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
          <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
          <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
          <dbname><![CDATA[lalcointeriors]]></dbname>
          <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
          <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
          <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
          <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
          <active>1</active>
      </connection>
 </default_setup>
```

When i running my website then it showing the following error message

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lalcointeriors.sl_less_file' doesn't exist

Trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\lib\Varien\Data\Collection\Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\lib\Varien\Data\Collection\Db.php(566): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\community\Soczed\Less\Model\Observer.php(112): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1338): Soczed_Less_Model_Observer->beforeLayoutRender(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Soczed_Less_Model_Observer), 'beforeLayoutRen...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(384): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...')
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(SkyMagento_Redirect_IndexController), 'lalco-home-page')
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(SkyMagento_Redirect_IndexController), 'lalco-home-page')
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\index.php(92): Mage::run('', 'store')
#23 {main}
```

Please help me to find the solution . It already takes my whole day

Comment: I checked my live db.there is no lalcointeriors.sl_less_file

Comment: You need to find the setup file related sl_less_file in core_resource table
when you get it, just delete that entry in core_resource table and refresh the page, then table automatically created.

Comment: @Rajan there is less_setup file only no sl_less_file are there

Comment: Yes, delete entry of less_setup then refresh page,
table automatically created and also add less_Setup setup in core_resource table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

While import **DB in local** this table is missed `lalcointeriors.sl_less_file`  check your **Live DB** And **Local DB** all table available or not

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in ...
>   app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php:555 ...

This error was easy to fix because the problem was in the following line:

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->$callback[1]();
```

Instead it should be:

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1]}();
```

Comment: I checked my live db.there is no lalcointeriors.sl_less_file

Comment: this is any custom extension

Comment: What I do for this. I am new on magento please help me to find the solution

Comment: Did you check both live local DB all table are existing or not

Comment: Check my updated question. for checking you edit core file if it's work then change i

Comment: now its showing this error.     SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lalcointeriors.sales_flat_quote_address' doesn't exist

Comment: See you missed table first cross check both live and local this error means table not found

Comment: yes i know but i import from live and in live it showing 250 table and in my local its also showing 250 tables

Comment: delete var/cache and then check

Comment: It showing same error

Comment: then sorry No idea

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution for that

**First Solution**

```
app\code\community\Soczed\Less\sql\setup_folder\mysql4-install.php
```

there will be sql script run that code in phpmyadmin.

**Second Solution**

go to your **core_resource** table and delete the **module** entry of it.

Remove you **var/cache** folder.

Comment: I follow the first solution but it not working same problem showing

Comment: did the table created? and remove **var/cache** folder too after table is created

Comment: table is not created and i remove the cache folder

Comment: here is the sql query which i triggered.  CREATE TABLE `{$installer->getTable('less/file')}` (
    `file_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `path` text character set utf8 NOT NULL,
    `cache` text character set utf8 default NULL,
    `use_global_variables` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default 1,
    `force_global_variables` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default 0,
    `custom_variables` text character set utf8 default NULL,
    `force_rebuild` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`)
)

Comment: . now it showing this error message.  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php:555 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()

Comment: #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(SkyMagento_Redirect_IndexController), 'lalco-home-page') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(SkyMagento_Redirect_IndexController), 'lalco-home-page') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalcointeriors\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()

Comment: @xr33dx go to `app/etc/modules/Soczed_Less.xml` and change `true` to `false`

Answer (score 0):

Check all your custom module code and try to find table name `sl_less_file`.

Take that module setup folder name and search that name in core resource table and remove that record. Also disable your cache first and then check.

OR

Create this table in your database

```
CREATE TABLE sl_less_file (
    `file_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `path` text character set utf8 NOT NULL,
    `cache` text character set utf8 default NULL,
    `use_global_variables` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default 1,
    `force_global_variables` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default 0,
    `custom_variables` text character set utf8 default NULL,
    `force_rebuild` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: now its showing this error. SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lalcointeriors.sales_flat_quote_address' doesn't exist

Comment: Then check this table is in your DB or not "sales_flat_quote_address". If not then your DB is not proper. Than download the DB again and set it again

Comment: @xr33dx, is your issue resolved ?

Comment: no i am working on it